# Maintainable approach to adding a title to an exsheets question?

Tags: exsheets

I've started using cgnieder's wonderful `exsheets` package for my problem sets, but it seems to be missing a valuable functionality: exercise titles. In my case, the latter would prove particularly useful because

- they can provide a concise (if somewhat cryptic) description of the exercise; and
- intriguing/cheeky titles can be effective at raising students' interest.

Ideally, an exercise with a title would look something like that:

[image]

However, `exsheets` doesn't seem to offer that title functionality out of the box: no `title` (or similar) key is defined for the `question` environment. My workaround so far is to

1. locally switch the `headings` option to `runin`,
2. typeset the exercise's title manually at the beginning of the `question` environment,
3. add a linebreak.

However, that approach is not very satisfying in terms of maintainability.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\SetupExSheets{headings=runin}
\begin{question}
\textbf{Fermat's last theorem}\\
\kant[1]
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

I very much wish there were a `title` option. Before I start dissecting `exhseets.sty` with the hope of producing a solution...

- Am I missing something obvious in the documentation? Is it an RTFM case?
- If not, how can I create a `title` key for the exsheets' `question` environment that would do the job?

Comment: You will  get paid for doing this, right? :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit 2015/05/16:**

`exsheets` questions have a `subtitle` option (since v0.10, 2013/10/11). In order to use it one needs to activate a headings instance which uses subtitles:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{
  headings = block-subtitle ,
  subtitle-format = \bfseries % default is \itshape
}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}[subtitle=Fermat's last theorem]
  \kant[1]
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  \kant[2]
\end{question}

\begin{question}[subtitle=L'H\^opital's rule]
  \kant[3]
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

---

**Original answer:**

You can use two things:

1. `exsheets` headings are defined with the help of the [`xtemplate`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xtemplate) package. They have lot's of hooks that can be used to customize them. Here you'll want the `number-post-code` hook.
2. The options of the `question` environments are set in the module `exsheets/question` with `l3keys`. New options are easily added.

[image]

Here's the complete code for an example. I tried adding comments explaining what's going on:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% new tokenlist variable:
\tl_new:N \l_exsheets_question_title_extra_tl

% new key that sets this variable:
\keys_define:nn { exsheets / question }
  { title .tl_set:N = \l_exsheets_question_title_extra_tl }

% extend the `block' instance to place the extra title part
% after the title number; we use the hook `number-post-code`
% for this:
\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{block-extended}{default}{
  join = { title[r,B]number[l,B](1ex,0pt) } ,
  attach = {
    main[l,vc]title[l,vc](0pt,0pt) ;
    main[r,vc]points[l,vc](\marginparsep,0pt)
  } ,
  number-post-code = {
    \tl_use:N \c_space_tl
    \tl_use:N \l__exsheets_heading_title_user_format_tl
    \tl_use:N \l_exsheets_question_title_extra_tl
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% use the new instance:
\SetupExSheets{headings=block-extended}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}[title=Fermat's last theorem]
  \kant[1]
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  \kant[2]
\end{question}

\begin{question}[title=L'H\^opital's rule]
  \kant[3]
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The man himself! That's great! Would you consider adding that key to a future version of `exsheets`?

Comment: @Jubobs I might :) One thing to solve remains: if `solution`s are added they won't pick up the extra title part with the solution above...

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. That might be a valuable addition, but I personally only need titles for the questions: by choosing intriguing/cheeky titles, I'm hoping to raise student's interest in them. Thanks again for your answer and for `exsheets`!

Comment: @Jubobs I think that I'll release v0.10 in the next few days. It will contain a solution for adding subtitles (when a heading instance is chosen that supports it).

Comment: That's great. I'm sure it will be useful to other people as well.

Comment: Last-minute suggestion: what do you think of adding a key for *indicative duration*, i.e. the expected time that an average student would require to complete the exercise?

Comment: @Jubobs I'm not convinced: for one thing I think that this may put extra pressure on students and thus should be avoided in exams (_could_ be helpful in exercises, though); more importantly I think there a various possibilities of adding such information already... (BTW: we shouldn't discuss feature requests in comments. But you can always email me...)

Comment: I agree with you about exams, but I think an indicative duration can be useful in labs/tutorials that consists in multiple exercises, because it gives students a licence to skip an exercise if they've been stuck on it for too long. Sorry for discussing feature requests here. I'll use email for future communication.

Comment: I've been trying to implement this solution but I keep getting an Undefined control sequence error on \begin{question}. Could it be babel? I'm using spanish.

Comment: @Majoko the error message surely tells you *which* control sequence is undefined. This is important to know, otherwise everything's is pure guesswork

Comment: The full error is:
[26] (./prob/econ_cerrada-problemas.tex
./prob/econ_cerrada-problemas.tex:1: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           Erroneous variable \l__exsheets_heading_title_use...
l.1 \begin{question}

But I have realized you now have implemented an "official" way of adding subtitles...

Comment: @Majoko actually quite a while ago, see my updated answer